# Modal appears on Chrome/Firefox but not safari?

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, safari

I have a "a" tag labeled "shoe_tag" that links to a url, and the following js code below:

```
$(".shoe_tag").on('click', function() {

    tpos = $(window).scrollTop() + 300;
    myModal.open();
    $(".scotch-modal").css({top:tpos, position:'absolute'});


});
```

This code allows me to open a modal while the server responds, which normally takes about 4 seconds. On Chrome and Firefox, the modal will open while the browser waits for the server response, but on Safari no modal opens. However, if I put a debugger statement right at the end, then call "myModal.open()" in the web console, then the modal will appear. Its almost like Safari skips over this code unless I call it in the console. I've been researching Safari based stuff for over a week and am stumped, any ideas?

Comment: it should have been var tpos rather than tpos

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i think that it's a problem with the rendering pipeline of the browser, try showing the modal after a short time:

```
$(".shoe_tag").on('click', function() {

    var tpos = $(window).scrollTop() + 300;
    $(".scotch-modal").css({top:tpos, position:'absolute'});
    setTimeout(function(){myModal.open();}, 100);

});
```

Timers saved my life many many times ;-)

Answer (score 0):

try

```
var tpos = $("body").scrollTop() + 300;
```

Webkit browsers always render window/html scrollTop as zero.

Comment: Its not a position issue, when I press "back" in the browser, the modal is for some reason there, and in the correct position. Its like once Safari makes a request, it doesn't render anything else on the page?

Comment: Can you create a plunker and share. By that it will be easier for me to debug.